Understanding the proof of Rao-Blackwell Theorem
I'm having problems on understanding the Rao-Blackwell theorem. In particular I don't understand why the resulting estimator is the one with minimum variance between ALL unbiased estimators of the parameter. The proof of the theorem just states that the variance of the resulting estimator is less than the variance of the estimator that I use for conditioning.

@User1865345 what i wanted to say is that we only prove that given V unbiased estimator and T sufficient statistic and we compute W=E[V|T] that the Var(W<=Var(V) but not Var(W)<=Var(S) where S is any other unbiased estimator

Let $(\Omega_X, \mathscr F_X,\mathfrak M:=\{P_\theta\mid \theta\in\Theta\}) $ be a statistical experiment and $\mathfrak M$ be dominated. Consider the collection of unbiased estimators of $ \theta$ as $\mathfrak U. $
$\bullet$  Rao-Blackwell states if $T$ is sufficient for $\mathfrak M, $ then $\mathbb E(U\mid T) \in\mathfrak U$ for $U\in\mathfrak U$ and $\operatorname{var}_\theta(U) \geq \operatorname{var}_\theta (\mathbb E(U\mid T)). $
$\bullet$ If $T$ is complete and $U\in\mathfrak U$ is measurable $\sigma(T(\mathbf X)), $ that is, $U$ is a measurable function of $T, $ then for any other $U^\prime\in\mathfrak U, $ for each $\theta\in\Theta, $ $$\operatorname{var}_\theta(U^\prime)\geq \operatorname{var}_\theta(U).$$
This follows from the fact that for each $\theta\in\Theta,$ $$\mathbb E_\theta[\mathbb E(U^\prime\mid T)-\mathbb E(U\mid T)]=0~~[P_\theta]$$ and $T$ being complete implying $\mathbb E(U^\prime\mid T)= \mathbb E(U\mid T)$ almost surely $P_\theta.$ Again $$\operatorname{var}_\theta(U^\prime)\geq \operatorname{var}_\theta (\mathbb E(U^\prime\mid T))=\operatorname{var}_\theta (\mathbb E(U\mid T))=\operatorname{var}_\theta (U),$$ the last equality being due to the fact that $U$ was assumed to be measurable function of $T$ and hence $U=\mathbb E(U\mid T). $

[I]f an unbiased estimator in $\frak U$ is measurable with respect to a complete and sufficient statistic its variance reaches the lower bound among $\frak U.$

--
Reference:
A Graduate Course on Statistical Inference, Bing Li, G. Jogesh Babu, Springer Science$+$Business, $2019, $ sec. $2.5.$
